# Integrate VISPY into WX

Tags: python, wxpython, vispy

I am struggling to get the bellow code (MWE) working.

Expected behavior: python quits after closing all windows

Observed behavior: python keeps running

Has anybody a clue why python does not quit?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
from vispy import scene


class Canvas(scene.SceneCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        scene.SceneCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,)


class VispyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Vispy Frame", wx.DefaultPosition, size=(500, 500))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SHOW, self.on_show)

        self.canvas = Canvas(app="wx", parent=self)

    def on_close(self, event):
        print("close")
        self.canvas.app.quit()
        self.canvas.close()
        self.Destroy()

    def on_show(self, event):
        print("show")
        self.canvas.show()


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "WX Frame")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="VISPY")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newwindow, button)

    def newwindow(self, event):
        secondWindow = VispyFrame(parent=self.panel)
        secondWindow.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame()
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this later, the github issue filed by @gkft walks through a few things that ended up working.

https://github.com/vispy/vispy/issues/1965